# Add edge between two documents in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

It should be easy operation but I can't find how to achieve this.
I have two documents from different collections and now I want to link them using new Edge from existing collection. I'm trying to use edge-collection.save function like this: 
`edge-collection.save(FOR s IN Sy
FILTER s._key=403560128,FOR i IN Im
FILTER i._key=353031872, points)` but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edge-collection.save()` does not expect AQL statements as you are trying to insert. It is expecting raw `_id` attributes for from and to and as a thir parameter a  JSON Object containing additional data for the edge.
To store the edge described in your example you can execute the following command:

`edge-collection.save("Sy/403560128", "Im/353031872", points);
                        ^^^^^             ^^^^^       ^^^^
                       sourceId          targetId     JSON`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried to do it like you said but still no luck. syntax error, unexpected identifier What this JSON object points should consist off?

Comment: The points variable can be any JSON object, including the empty one `{}`. `Sy` and `Im` have to be valid collections in your ArangoDB.

Working example:
`var points = {"my": "test"};edge-collection.save("Sy/403560128", "Im/353031872", points);`

Comment: Yes, Sy and Im is existing collections in my ArangoDB. Problem may be with this points JSON. What does it do? I thought it should be a name of edge collection I want to create edge for.

Comment: Ah now i got it. Points is some additional data you want to store in the edge (it can contain arbitrary data same as documents). This has nothing todo with the edge collection. You have to replace the `edge-collection` thing with your collection name. So if you want to save an empty edge in the `points` collection you have to execute: `points.save("Sy/403560128", "Im/353031872", {});`

Comment: Oh, thank you @mchacki. Now I've got another error: points is not defined even so db._collections() shows [ArangoCollection 295753408, "points" (type edge, status loaded)] but this is maybe another story :)

Comment: Have found what was the last problem: should use db.points.save("Sy/403560128", "Im/353031872", {});

Comment: oh sorry, thought you allready bound points to a variable. `var points = db.points` Glad it worked now.